# Windows 7 Virtual Machine running off SSD on VirtualBox Lubuntu

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, lubuntu

I downloaded the Windows 7 OVA from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/linux/

I imported into Virtualbox, set the storage to be a fixed 4GB on an external SSD, and when I launch it, it goes into a reboot loop where it says "Loading Windows Files..."

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: What do you mean "set the storage"? The ova should already contain a virtual disk.

Comment: Sorry, the question is how do I get virtualbox to load windows 7.  Sorry, I meant I have my vdi saved on my external ssd